# Excel - refer to relative cell in formula based on criteria

Tags: excel

I have column A where from row 3 to row 200 there are D, C and G accounts. Row 3 to 44 is D; row 45 to 100 is C and row 101 to 202 is G.

It can be that next month, D is row 3 to 46; C is then starting at 47 etc.

I need a formula fix so that my `index(match(` can refer to the first occurence of "C"-1 when the #of D's change
`INDEX(GAC!$A$44:$AF$252;MATCH`

Thx 4 help

Comment: in this way it is almost impossibile to understand the problem. Could you please paste a small example? I suggest you to make an excel sheet and paste into this site https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ selecting Header Location: SpreadSheet.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what you are asking, but maybe the following will help.

```
=MATCH("C",A3:A202,0)+ROW(A3:A202)-1
```

This gives you the row number of the first instance of C in your list and so you could use this information inside your INDEX MATCH formula. Depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you; but I need it in vba language because it is part of a bigger custom function :)

Comment: In this case please edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: Also, you can use the function inside VBA, so could you please clarify why it does not answer your problem.